# MVC Core @Html.TextBoxFor How to add Style inside this new Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Need help here. How do I add style and class inside this textboxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Student, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", false } })
```

I tried to do something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Student, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", false }, new {style="font-size:30px", class="form-control" })`
```

But apparently its not the correct format

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you're using a C# anonymous-type for `htmlAttributes` then prefix the member name with the `@` character to escape C# keywords like `class`:

  ```
  @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Foo, new { style="color: red;", @class="baz" } )
  ```
- If you're using a `Dictionary` typed object then use dictionary-initializer syntax:

  ```
  @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Foo, new Dictionary<String,Object> { { "style", "color: red;" }, { "class", "baz" } } );
  ```

  In C#, the syntax `new DictionaryType { { a, b }, { c, d }, { e, f }, ... }`

  ...is compiled into inline `Add( key, value )` statements:

  ```
  DictionaryType dict = new DictionaryType();
  dict.Add( a, b );
  dict.Add( c, d );
  dict.Add( e, f );
  return dict;
  ```